# What is the "correct" notion of a perfect graded commutative algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, koszul-duality, l-infinity-algebras

My question is rather simplistic. While trying to dualize some statements about rational homotopy algebra of a space I got stuck with the following problem.

We have a notion of a perfect Lie algebra in the sense that its abelianization is trivial.  But what is the Koszul dual version of this concept? The definition of a perfect algebra over a field of positive characteristic or the [definition of Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring) seem to be irrelevant in this context. However, I may be missing some crucial link or complete triviality of my question for one way or another. One can think of everything here in $L_\infty$ sense, I believe it does not matter.